# Use "generate code" of IntelliJ for more classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, code-generation, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ have a very useful option called "generate code", that I can apply to a class for generating code regarding constructors, getters, setters etc...

Unfortunately, this seems to work for only one Java class at once. It is possible to apply to multiple classes at once?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tool for batch Generate code action in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @Lore, I started using lombok plugin and with this plugin we don't even need to generate the code every time and the class looks even more cleaner and we can access the class fields too , JUST A SUGGESTION :)

Comment: I know the plugin, but in this project I can't use it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. It's **one at a time**.

I tried searching if we can generate code for multiple classes at once using IntelliJ's "generate code", I didn't find any option for such activity. Tried few options in local too with no success.

Even in Jetbrains helps section I don't see such an article which can help in this.

Comment: I would take a look at the Groovy script that IntelliJ uses to generate the getters/setters/etc. then see if you can modify it to accept more than one class. You may have to write a custom plugin, or do this from a script outside of the IDE.

Comment: @DustinR it's a good idea. let's try and update here if we are lucky in doing that.